# MySQL sum of change in growth and order by growth

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hello I have two tables on for portfolio and and for stock data details. I want to find out how much the total growth of users portfolio by changes of price. For example:

User A:

stock A  -4.41

Stock B -1.49

Stock C 0.38

Stock D  1.43

User B

Stock A  -2.05

Stock B  .05

I want to show table like: USER   Growth

```
                        A      -4.09

                        B      -2.1
```

here are my two tables: one portfolio where all buy sell info's are kept of users by user_id

```
 +-------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
 | Field             | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
 +-------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
 | portfolio_ID      | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
 | user_id           | int(11)       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
 | contest_id        | int(11)       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
 | company_id        | int(11)       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
 | share_amount      | int(11)       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
 | buy_price         | decimal(9,2)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
 | total_buy_price   | decimal(10,4) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
 | buy_date          | date          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
 | commision         | decimal(9,2)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
 | sell_share_amount | int(11)       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
 | sell_price        | decimal(10,2) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
 | total_sell_price  | decimal(16,2) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
 | sell_date         | date          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
 | sell_commision    | decimal(9,2)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
 +-------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Next the daily stock table:

```
 +-----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
 | Field           | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
 +-----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
 | company_id      | int(11)          | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
 | entry_date      | date             | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
 | entry_timestamp | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
 | open            | decimal(16,2)    | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
 | high            | decimal(16,2)    | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
 | low             | decimal(16,2)    | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
 | ltp             | decimal(16,2)    | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
 | ycp             | decimal(16,2)    | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
 | cse_price       | decimal(9,2)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
 | cse_volume      | decimal(18,2)    | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
 | total_trade     | int(30)          | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
 | total_volume    | int(30)          | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
 | total_value     | decimal(18,4)    | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
 | changes         | float(10,2)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
 | floating_cap    | float(16,2)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
 +-----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

this is the sql i am using:

```
 SELECT
 po.user_id,
 ((e.ltp-po.buy_price)/po.buy_price) AS growth
 FROM eod_stock AS e
 LEFT OUTER JOIN portfolio AS po
 ON e.company_id = po.company_id
 WHERE po.contest_id = 2
 GROUP BY po.user_id;
```

but it return only first changes not the sum of the changes of the growth, i then modified it like this:

```
 SELECT
 po.user_id,
 SUM((e.ltp-po.buy_price)/po.buy_price) AS growth
 FROM eod_stock AS e
 LEFT OUTER JOIN portfolio AS po
 ON e.company_id = po.company_id
 WHERE po.contest_id = 2
 GROUP BY growth
 ORDER BY growth DESC;
```

but it generates a error code 1056, cant group on growth

here is the sql fiddle: 
     http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b3a83/2

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Try grouping by `user_id`.

Comment: i already did that check my first sql.. but that returns wrong calculation of growth, you can check that

Comment: you can't group on a SUM since the SUM is a result of the grouping. Imagine saying "I have a fruitbasket and want to know how many of each fruit I have, and a type of fruit is defined by how many of that fruit I have". Notice how that results in a never-ending circle? That's basically what you are trying in your last query :) I would suggest trying what the user above me suggested, group by the user_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to group by `growth`.  Why did you change the `group by`?

```
SELECT po.user_id, SUM((e.ltp-po.buy_price)/po.buy_price) AS growth
FROM eod_stock e LEFT OUTER JOIN
     portfolio po
     ON e.company_id = po.company_id
WHERE po.contest_id = 2
GROUP BY po.user_id
ORDER BY growth DESC;
```

However, I suspect that you might actually want the maximum minus the minimum:

```
SELECT po.user_id,
       (MAX(e.ltp-po.buy_price) - MIN(e.ltp-po.buy_price))/po.buy_price) AS growth
FROM eod_stock e LEFT OUTER JOIN
     portfolio po
     ON e.company_id = po.company_id
WHERE po.contest_id = 2
GROUP BY po.user_id
ORDER BY growth DESC;
```

This gives an overall view over time.  However, it doesn't show the direction.  So something going from 50 to 100 gets the same value as something going from 100 to 50.  This can be fixed, if this is what you are really looking for.

Comment: I am really a silly, your first query is exactly returning what i need. Thanks but can you help me a little, i need to find the growth of all active stocks that means if he doesnt sell his stock, the logic can be like this if share_amount  != sell_share_amount then calulate that growth or if partial amount is there for example if 200 stock is in share amount and 100 in sell_share_amount the growth of 100 will be considered that i can get the real unrealized gain of all users. thanks for your help

Comment: @SamiaRuponti . . . Can you ask another question, providing sample data and desired results?

Comment: sample data is same that i provided in the sqlfiddle, the problem i am having here is its calculating all growth of users even user sold that stcok, for example if user a sold stock A then then i dont need to consider Stock A for my calculation. i can check that by cheking the share amount and sell_share_amount field, please check my above portfolio table for the reference, sell_share_amount is the amount sold out by the user, in short i need only gorowth of those stock in which share amount> sell_share_amount.

Comment: This is the answer for the updated question @Gordon Linoff

SELECT po.user_id, 
sum(CAST(((e.ltp-po.buy_price)/po.buy_price)*100 AS DECIMAL(10,2))) as growth
FROM eod_stock e LEFT OUTER JOIN
     portfolio po
     ON e.company_id = po.company_id AND e.entry_date = (SELECT MAX(entry_date) FROM eod_stock)
WHERE po.contest_id = 2
GROUP BY po.user_id
order by growth DESC;